# Choose instance class and automatic scaling for appengine app

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine

I tried some different settings for my appengine app with little or no result. Primarily I changed the instance class from F1 to F2 and all I experienced was higher costs and no performance gain. Now I reverted to the following settings

```
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true
module: default
instance_class: F2
automatic_scaling:
  min_idle_instances: 5
  max_idle_instances: automatic
  min_pending_latency: automatic
  max_pending_latency: 30ms
  max_concurrent_requests: 50

default_expiration: "14d 5h"
```

Does the above look alright? Why don't I experience a performance gain when changing instance class from F1 to F2? I do experience a great performance difference between memcache and the datastore roundtrip, therefore it seems that my only chance of speeding up my response times for my app is to use memcache more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instance classes exist to support scaling.  An instance with more RAM and a faster CPU can handle more concurrent requests than a less powerful instance.  So upgrading instances allows an application to handle more traffic, but the effect on individual request times is likely to be marginal unless the requests use a lot of RAM or are CPU-bound.

In App Engine, datastore queries are IO-bound, because they send a request over the network.  Making a lot of sequential datastore calls increases response times.  You can use the cloud console trace facilities or [Appstats](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/appstats) to view the remote procedure calls that your requests are making.  Use [ndb's asynchronous operations](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/async) to reduce the amount of time your app spends waiting on datastore calls, and [tasklets](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/async#parallel_queries_yield) to parallellise datastore reads.